# CodeIgniter: Failed opening required '<<document_root>>/system/database/drivers/dbdriver/dbdriver_driver.php'

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter, and I want to connect to two databases to get the values in the same file. I googled around a bit and found that we can do that by using:

```
    $dsn1 = 'dbdriver://user:pass@ip/db1';  
    $dsn2 = 'dbdriver://user:pass@ip/db2';
    $DB1 = $this->load->database($dsn1,TRUE);
    $DB2 = $this->load->database($dsn2,TRUE);
```

Now this gives the error saying that 
`dbdriver_driver.php` file is not present.

This is a fresh installation.

And I will post the contents of the database folder shortly.

Edit: There is no drivers folder in the database directory

Edit2: It says no such file or directory, and that is true. Should I install addons for this to work or did I somewhere make a mistake or forget a part during installation of codeigniter

Edit 3: The database.php file:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

The hostname, username and password are set as well.

Comment: Add error in here...

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju, Done

Comment: No, the way you are trying seems correct. see this link, https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: @Quicksillver add `database.php` file as well

Comment: @Quicksillver so where is your multiple db settings ??

Comment: @Abdulla There aren't any, I'm just following the method specified here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: you use `$dsn1 = 'dbdriver://user:pass@ip/db1';  
    $dsn2 = 'dbdriver://user:pass@ip/db2';` so there should be two db settings file

Comment: @Abdulla, I didn't know that.nI'm new to this framework. Can you please tell me where I have to configure those files, or point me to a link that helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing apples with potatoes here. This is how your `config/database.php` should look like:

```
$active_group = 'db1';  // the default db connection. 
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['db1']['hostname'] = 'localhost';//or ip
$db['db1']['username'] = 'username';
$db['db1']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['db1']['database'] = 'db_name';
$db['db1']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['db1']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db1']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['db1']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['db1']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db1']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db1']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db1']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['db1']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db1']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db1']['stricton'] = FALSE;

// the second db connection configuration
$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';//or ip
$db['db2']['username'] = 'username';
$db['db2']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['db2']['database'] = 'db_name';
$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db2']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

So you have two database connections configured. Now, you must use them like this, inside controllers or model functions:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('db1',TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('db2',TRUE);
```

**EDIT:** 
Your DSN variable should have everything needed to establish a connection, **it will not look inside `config/database.php` file**. I suppose you diddn't actually change 'dbdriver' key-word in `$dsn1 = 'dbdriver://user:pass@ip/db1;` string to the actual db engine name (?), like 'mysql', 'msqli', 'pdo' or whatever engine you use.

So if you write 'dbdriver', CI expects to find a folder named 'dbdriver'(with that exact name) inside 'system/database/drivers/' directory, and a php file named '***dbdriver***_driver.php'. If you write '***mysql***', it will find the mysql driver file : 'system/database/drivers/***mysql***/***mysql***_driver.php'.
The other configuration variables, like pconnect, db_debug or whatever, should be mentioned as a query string:

```
$dsn1 = 'mysql://user:pass@ip/db1?pconnect=true&db_debug=false&etc...';
$dsn2 = 'pdo://user:pass@ip/db1?pconnect=true&db_debug=false&etc...';
```

Comment: While this works, I don't understand why my method fails because it is said [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html) that it should work, as we are defining the Database details on the go if I'm not  mistaken.

Comment: Thank you. And no I did not change the dbdriver to mysql. TIL thanks to you.